# How can I collect all my types into one table in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have got multiple type tables where I specify types of other tables. I use these types for form selections or other for use. For example I have a users table and a user_types. I have articles and article_types. I have images and image_types. But what I want is to use one table for all these and other tables. What relationship and system can I use for this?

```
users
id  name  surname  type
1   john  doe      1
2   jane  doe      2

user_types
id  title
1   Writer
2   Reader

articles
id  title  type  text
1   a man  1     a man is...
2   red B  3     there are ...

article_types
id  title
1   Story
2   News
3   Report

...
```

Here I can use the one to many relationship for users like:

```
class User extends Model
{
   public function type()
   {
       return $this->belongsTo(UserType::class);
   }
}

class UserType extends Model
{
   public function users()
   {
       return $this->hasMany(User::class);
   }
}
```

and now I can easily use:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->type()->title;
```

or simply get all types :

```
$userTypes = UserType::all();
```

But I want to gather all types into one table. Is there a way for that. Or should I better go with the old style?

Comment: You can always have all the types in one table but it better to have separate types in separate tables. OR have a type table with another column called `module` which says which module each type belongs to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at polymorphic relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Only one model is needed to store the type say, 'table_types' with at essential fields typeable_id, typeable_type

Define a relationship method in the model TableType

```
class TableType extends Model {

    public function typeable(){
    return $this->morphTo();
    }
    }
```

For each table you wanna track e.g.

```
class User extends Model {
public function type() {
return $this->morphMany('App\TableType', 'typeable');
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IMHO have a look at [Many to Many Polymorphic relations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations).

There is an example with tags that should fit well with your Types